# What is the syntax for Spark sql

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying write select statment in spark.sql.Please refer below syntax:

salesforce_df = spark.sql("SELECT
colname1,
colname2,
colname3
FROM tabname;")

But i am getting "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal"

```
colname1 has to appear in 1st row,
colname2 has to appear in 2nd row,
colname3 has to appear in 3rd row
```

Please advise

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZVp7.png)

Regards
Rohit

Comment: the above syntax of `spark.sql` it is correct, can you provide full code image with error.

Comment: I have updated in the main link only.I was not able to upload the image here

Answer (score 0):

For multiline strings you need to use triple quotes: double (`"""`) or single (`'''`) not a single (`"` or `'`). See [Python docs about the string type](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str).

```py
df = spark.sql("""select ....
from table""")
```